# How do I know if my IP is blacklisted for Deezer API?

Tags: api, blacklist, rate-limiting, deezer

On my local machine, I visit the url http://api.deezer.com/2.0/search/artist?q=feeder and get the correct json data returned. On my live server, I curl the same url, and get returned the json.

```
{"data":[],"total":0}
```

http status code is 200, and I don't believe I've hit the rate limit, having tested on my local machine with a similar load.

I can only suspect that someone else on the server (On a shared host here), has hit the API and got blacklisted, or they still respond when a rate limit is hit but with no notification of that fact.

Anyone got any suggestions? Currently short of waiting a few hours and trying again, I'm stumped.

(P.S. Anyone with enough rep want to make a "Deezer" tag?)

Comment: I've made a Deezer tag as I am working with a project centered around Deezer data and too think it would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this exact question to Deezer devs. The answer is that you need to have an access token to consume the data this way.

See more here: http://developers.deezer.com/api/oauth

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is indeed correct. I contacted them a while back, went back and forth a bit to get to the bottom of things. I should have updated here with the answer, so thanks =]