# simplexml_load_file works on a local machine, doesn't work online

Tags: php, xml, dreamhost, deezer

I'm using Deezer APIs

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.deezer.com/2.0//search/artist/?q=eminem&index=0&nb_items=1&output=xml');

var_dump($xml);

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/393/top/&output=xml');

var_dump($xml);
```

The first call works in the same way both on my local machine (Mac PHP 5.3.15) and online on a dream-host server (PHP 5.3.13), the second call works on my local machine, reporting all 5 track objects, but not on-line, where I just get

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { 
 ["data"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { } 
 ["total"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) { } 
}
```

It seems to me very weird, do you have any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work the json way like so `$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/393/top/?output=json'),false);` ?

Comment: even in this case, it works locally and not on-line

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($http_response_header);` on the server after the first and after the second `simplexml_load_file()`?

Comment: array(9) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" [1]=> string(35) "Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2013 12:14:43 GMT" [2]=> string(14) "Server: Apache" [3]=> string(80) "P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml" CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"" [4]=> string(21) "Vary: Accept-Encoding" [5]=> string(18) "X-Node: blm-web-04" [6]=> string(18) "Content-Length: 92" [7]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [8]=> string(44) "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8" } 

locally the last part is
..."Content-Length: 2365" [7]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [8]=> string(44) ....

Comment: The last part was the one I was interested in :) The Content-Length-header indicates that an empty result-set is returned, so there must be some issue with the API. Maybe it doesn't like you server's IP address due to country restrictions. Or maybe some other headers are missing. But that's kind of weird, there seems to be no problem when I call it in my browser.

Comment: The other API call works so I don't think the reason is the server IP...the server answers with the correct xml nodes (data and total) but the answer looks like that artist doesn't have any track....very weird...
I also tried several artists, getting similar results...

Comment: This
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278297/how-do-i-know-if-my-ip-is-blacklisted-for-deezer-api
seems very related and I will investigate, even if it is strange that with another API call the result is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deezer use geolocation for Artist Request.

So, if your server is geolocated in US for example, the first request have the same result between local and online but de second one (http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/393/top/&output=xml) don't have the same result local/online.

Request with FR Ip :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><data><track><id><![CDATA[2114267]]></id><readable><![CDATA[1]]></readable><title><![CDATA[My Life]]></title><link><![CDATA[http://www.deezer.com/track/2114267]]></link><duration><![CDATA[321]]></duration><rank><![CDATA[674751]]></rank><preview><![CDATA[http://cdn-preview-2.deezer.com/stream/2ecb4b24f51cdbfdaea89630f1978529-0.mp3]]></preview><artist><id><![CDATA[393]]></id><name><![CDATA[The Game]]></name></artist><type><![CDATA[track]]></type></track><track><id><![CDATA[2307182]]></id><readable><![CDATA[1]]></readable><title><![CDATA[Hate It Or Love It]]></title><link><![CDATA[http://www.deezer.com/track/2307182]]></link><duration><![CDATA[207]]></duration><rank><![CDATA[654207]]></rank><preview><![CDATA[http://cdn-preview-3.deezer.com/stream/393350005d03712abc9adfbe2bcfe2d3-0.mp3]]></preview><artist><id><![CDATA[393]]></id><name><![CDATA[The Game]]></name></artist><type><![CDATA[track]]></type></track><track><id><![CDATA[2294433]]></id><readable><![CDATA[1]]></readable><title><![CDATA[How We Do]]></title><link><![CDATA[http://www.deezer.com/track/2294433]]></link><duration><![CDATA[235]]></duration><rank><![CDATA[610398]]></rank><preview><![CDATA[http://cdn-preview-c.deezer.com/stream/c3683a1fc1899c9d1b128b222d0e080f-1.mp3]]></preview><artist><id><![CDATA[393]]></id><name><![CDATA[The Game]]></name></artist><type><![CDATA[track]]></type></track><track><id><![CDATA[62751648]]></id><readable><![CDATA[1]]></readable><title><![CDATA[Ali Bomaye]]></title><link><![CDATA[http://www.deezer.com/track/62751648]]></link><duration><![CDATA[373]]></duration><rank><![CDATA[571988]]></rank><preview><![CDATA[http://cdn-preview-1.deezer.com/stream/1bb2606c722235eeecb2b1caa039f5c1-0.mp3]]></preview><artist><id><![CDATA[393]]></id><name><![CDATA[The Game]]></name></artist><type><![CDATA[track]]></type></track><track><id><![CDATA[61571949]]></id><readable><![CDATA[1]]></readable><title><![CDATA[Celebration]]></title><link><![CDATA[http://www.deezer.com/track/61571949]]></link><duration><![CDATA[290]]></duration><rank><![CDATA[559639]]></rank><preview><![CDATA[http://cdn-preview-f.deezer.com/stream/f1f535359bd60ce3ec77d59fcfda4ebd-1.mp3]]></preview><artist><id><![CDATA[393]]></id><name><![CDATA[The Game]]></name></artist><type><![CDATA[track]]></type></track></data><total><![CDATA[5]]></total></root>
```

The same request with US location :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><data></data><total><![CDATA[0]]></total></root>
```

To complete the answer. You can change Geolocation of your request (and have result from US Server) with access_token of user located in non-restricted country because when you request the deezer api with access_token, the api will use the user country and not the server country.

To get an access token from user :
http://developers.deezer.com/api/oauth

Don't forget on each request when you want to use the User geolocation to add this :

```
?access_token=XXXXX
```

EDIT :
I am part of the deezer team.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed your answer; I came to the same results in the meantime, but your answer is of course right. Thanks!
The thing I don't understand is: even the server side procedure to get the token is geolocated so I can't get a token from a US server, and the token is needed (as you wrote)! Of course I can use client-side auth procedure but I need it server side for my application

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access xml by http protocol you will need to set allow_url_fopen ON in php.ini or

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen ','ON');
```

in your code. or you can also do this if you are using php version <5

```
$temp = file_get_contents($url);
 $XmlObj = simplexml_load_string($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/393/top/?output=xml');
```

(i.e. change the '&' to '?')

This may or may not be the problem.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work; I also think it is related to the URL.